# How do I load different content on different dropdown selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a dropdown menu with options like:

- "**All**"
- "**21 April 2019**"
- "**22 April 2019**"
- "**23 April 2019**"

I have 4 divs:

- "**All Tabs**"
- "**21 April Tab**"
- "**22nd April Tab**"
- "**23 April Tab**"

So what I want to achieve is if I select "**All**" from dropdown, the "**All Tabs**" div should load only, and if I select "**21 April 2019**", the "**21 April Tab**" should load only, and likewise.

How can I achieve it?

Regards,
Bill

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin=" anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="card shadow-2 mb-3">
  <div class="card-header">
    <div class="col-9 pl-0 float-left">
      <h4 class="card-heading mt-3 pt-2">
        Price Breakdown
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 float-right">
      <select class="form-control custom-select" id="conditionsselect1">
        <option selected="selected" value="">All</option>
        <option>21 April 2019</option>
        <option>22 April 2019</option>
        <option>23 April 2019</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>All Tab</div>
  <div>21 April Tab</div>
  <div>22 April Tab</div>
  <div>23 April Tab</div>

</div>
```

Comment: if you select `21 April 2019` then it might show first row? or ask the question clear.

Comment: I see you are trying to use jquery. You should try to understand how basic JavaScript is written and then read some basic jquery guides to get an idea how basic dom manipulation is accomplished. You should be able to figure out a solution on your own after that. For stackoverflow, this question is a bit too broad as you haven't provided an attempt to make it work.

Comment: _“must be replaced with the associated content”_ - and what _is_ the associated content? _How_ did you associate anything with anything here?

Comment: @UdhayTitus I have improved my question. Maybe it's more easier to understand now?

Comment: @04FS Revised the question, can you have a look, please.

Comment: firstly you would need to have some way to associate the divs with the tab options, e.g. using classes or data-attributes to match the value of the option. Then you'd need to write some code which would detect a click on a tab button, find the related div (by selecting the one with the matching attribute), hide all the tabs, and then show the one you've found as the matching one. So...that's the logical process, but what have you researched or tried so far yourself? Did you look into it at all?

Comment: P.S. Having said all that, I see you've included Bootstrap, and bootstrap basically provides this functionality out of the box. See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#tabs and https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#javascript-behavior. Did you notice this during your research?

Comment: Yes, I know about Bootstrap tabs, but that won't work with the select option? Am I right?

Comment: There's even https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#tabs-with-dropdowns as well. But at the end of the day does it really matter if it's a dropdown or a horizontal menu? I guess maybe you are planning to have a large number of options which might not fit horizontally, that's all I can assume?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

are you trying something like this

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#conditionsselect1").change(function(){
    var val = $("#conditionsselect1").val();    
  //  $('.dyn-div:contains("'+val+'")').show();   

       $(".dyn-div").hide();
       $(".dyn-div."+val+"").show();
  });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
       $(".dyn-div").hide();
       $(".dyn-div."+$("#conditionsselect1").val()+"").show();
  $("#conditionsselect1").change(function(){
    var val = $("#conditionsselect1").val();    
  //  $('.dyn-div:contains("'+val+'")').show();   
  //  if(val == "all")
  //  {
  //    $(".dyn-div").show();
  //  }
  //  else
  //  {
       $(".dyn-div").hide();
       $(".dyn-div."+val+"").show();
  //  }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin=" anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="card shadow-2 mb-3">
  <div class="card-header">
    <div class="col-9 pl-0 float-left">
      <h4 class="card-heading mt-3 pt-2">
        Price Breakdown
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 float-right">
      <select class="form-control custom-select" id="conditionsselect1">
        <option selected="selected" value="all">All</option>
        <option value="one">21 April 2019</option>
        <option value="two">22 April 2019</option>
        <option value="three">23 April 2019</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="dyn-div all">All Tab</div>
  <div class="dyn-div one">21 April Tab</div>
  <div class="dyn-div two">22 April Tab</div>
  <div class="dyn-div three">23 April Tab</div>

</div>
```

Comment: This works, but IMO it would be better to set an attribute to match the div by rather than rely on the content of the div, which could easily be altered. Ideally an "value" would be set on the dropdown options for the same purpose too, so that if the description changes in future (or can be varied, e.g. different date formats in different locales) it does not break the code. The operation of functionality should not depend on the specifics of the UI appearance.

Comment: @ADyson So we have to do by id or class name some thing like that I may right? Based on dropdown value we have to match id or some other attr

Comment: In my opinion that would be a more sustainable way to do it than this solution, yes

Answer (score 1):

Please check this may be helpful.

```js
 $(".jqSelector").change(function(){
     $(".dataDivs").hide();
     var optn = $(this).find(':selected').attr('data-show');
     //alert(optn);
     $("." + optn).show();
     
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin=" anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card shadow-2 mb-3">
  <div class="card-header">
    <div class="col-9 pl-0 float-left">
      <h4 class="card-heading mt-3 pt-2">
        Price Breakdown
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 float-right">
      <select class="form-control custom-select jqSelector" id="conditionsselect1">
        <option selected="selected" value="" data-show="all">All</option>
        <option data-show="first">21 April 2019</option>
        <option data-show="second">22 April 2019</option>
        <option data-show="third">23 April 2019</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="dataDivs all">All Tab</div>
  <div class="dataDivs all first">21 April Tab</div>
  <div class="dataDivs all second">22 April Tab</div>
  <div class="dataDivs all third">23 April Tab</div>

</div>
```

Comment: the question says "if I select "All" from dropdown, the "All Tabs" div should load only"...but your code doesn't do that.

Comment: I think here is all mean show all information if not just remove all class in information divs.

Comment: what makes you think that? The question says, quite specifically, "the All Tabs div should load **only**" . I don't know if the OP really wants that, but that's what they are currently asking for. We can't second-guess their intention. If you're not sure what something in the question means, post a comment before answering, and get clarification from the OP.

Comment: @chandershekhar AD is right. Is there any way I can only show "All Tab" when I select "All" option which is by default. The rest seems fine!

Comment: @BillNathan in this case just remove the class "all" from the last 3 divs. Also if "all" is always selected by default at the start, you might want to consider making the last 3 divs hidden by default, so they don't show up when the page first loads. Adding the attribute `style="display:none;"` to each of those 3 divs would achieve that.

Answer (score -1):

I have made some changes in the HTML and i have added some jquery code. Just go through the code u will get some idea how to approach the problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin=" anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script>
 $('#conditionsselect1').on('change',function(){

    let selectVal= $(this).children("option").filter(":selected").attr('class');

    $('body table tbody').find('tr').hide();

    $('body table tbody').find('tr[class="'+selectVal+'"]').show();

})

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="card shadow-2 mb-3">
  <div class="card-header">
    <div class="col-9 pl-0 float-left">
      <h4 class="card-heading mt-3 pt-2">
        Price Breakdown
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 float-right">
      <select class="form-control custom-select" id="conditionsselect1">
        <option value="all" class="all">All</option>
        <option class="21">21 April 2019</option>
        <option class="22">22 April 2019</option>
        <option class="23">23 April 2019</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <table class="table table-user-information">
    <thead>
    <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>Gross</th>
          <th>Net</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>    
      <tr class="21">
        <td>Hello</td>
        <td>£30.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="22">
        <td>Hello 1</td>
        <td>£10.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="23">
        <td>Hello 2</td>
        <td>£7.00</td>
        <td>£7.00</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```